# How to unregister a selenium grid node using chef

Tags: selenium-grid

I have a chef recipe that registers a node to a hub on the default port. But if the recipe is run on the node again , it gives me error which indicates that the port is already in use. So I need to have a check in place which either frees that port  (not ideal) or randomly assigns a port while chef-client is running. I would like to unregister a node from the hub using a recipe. How do I do that?

Comment: Impossible to diagnose this problem without seeing the cookbook code.

Comment: Its not about the cookbook code. But in general. Suppose you setup a hub. Register a node to it say 1.1.1.1:5555 .. now again if u register the same node it would give an error saying the port is already in use. Secondly. How can i unregister a node that is registered with a hub (it should not appear in the hub console)

Comment: So this question has nothing to do with chef?

Comment: Once I get to know how to do it manually I would be implementing it in a recipe. I have a cookbook that installs hub, registers node etc

Answer (score 0):

With Selenium 2.53, you can unregister a node with an http command:

http://node_ip_address:port/selenium-server/driver/?cmd=shutDownSeleniumServer
Regards